# фильтрация массива обьектов по наличию свойства в этом обьекте

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs

есть такой массив:

```
export const products = [
  {
    image: redLove,
    title: "Red Love Cup",
    price: "$25.00",
    oldPrice: "$37.00 USD",
  },
  {
    image: blackTea,
    title: "Black Tea Cup",
    price: "$15.00",
    oldPrice: "$29.00 USD",
  },
  {
    image: essentials,
    title: "B&W Essentials Mug",
    price: "$12.00",
    oldPrice: "$19.00 USD",
  },
  {
    image: winterStyle,
    title: "Winter Style Mug",
    price: "$25.00",
   
  },
  {
    image: ceramic,
    title: "Ceramic Tea",
    price: "$46.00",

    
  },
  {
    image: noHandleBar,
    title: "No Handle Bar Cup",
    price: "$34.00",

    
  },
  {
    image: espresso,
    title: "Espresso Cup by Mugs.co",
    price: "$25.00",

   
  },
  {
    image: pinkPremium,
    title: "Pink Premium Ceramic",
    price: "$99.00",

    
  },
  {
    image: summerDesigner,
    title: "Summer Designer Cup",
    price: "$29.00",

    
  },
];
```

При нажатии на радиобатон "ВСЕ" отрендерить все обьекты!
При нажатии на радиобатон "Скидки" отрендерить ТОЛЬКО обьекты со свойстом "oldPrice"!

Компонент в котором мапиться массив:

```
<div className={styles.imgWrapper}>
        {products.map((item) => (
          <ProductCard
            image={item.image}
            key={item.title}
            title={item.title}
            price={item.price}
            oldPrice={item.oldPrice}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div className={styles.imgWrapper}>
        {
            products.map((item) => (
                if ('oldPrice' in item) {
                    <ProductCard
                        image={item.image}
                        key={item.title}
                        title={item.title}
                        price={item.price}
                        oldPrice={item.oldPrice}
                    />
                }
        ))}
      </div>
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).